# How to use Universal image loader for video thumbnails listing in android?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have one activity which has listing of video file contains in SD card. I want to display video thumbnails and video name. But when I try to load this activity it take too much time to load and list scrolling not very smooth. I want to use Universal loader for this. But dont no how to use it with video thumbnails?Please help

Comment: How do you display thumbnails now?

Comment: I am creating thumbnail from video path stored in sd card.

Comment: Show the code ehich way you do this.

Comment: I hav solve the problem.Actually i was creating the thumbnail from the video file.Now i got the thumbnail video file that is already created by system and we just need to get through content resolver...Sorry for late reply...

Comment: Hello Bhargav. Can you post some sample code of your solution. I am trying to show video thumbnails using universal image loader. but the file path "file:///mnt/sdcard/Coke.mp4" doesnt seem to work with Universal Image Loader. Any suggestions. I am stuck here..

Comment: @Vansi- I hav also spent lots of time for displaying video thumbnail with universal loader but unable to succeeded.So finally i just get and display thumbnail from content resolver.You can also try this.